# Django error when following relationships backward

Tags: django, orm

I have two models:

Base_Activity:

```
topics = models.ManyToManyField(Topic)
... some others
```

User_Activity:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
activity = models.ForeignKey(Base_Activity)
is_archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now I want to query `Base_activity` to select all rows with *topic X* and exclude any rows that have a matching row in `User_Activity` for **user**=*current_user* and **is_archived**=*True*.

---

I have read the Django docs on how to [follow relationships backward](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward), since I query `Base_Activity`, but need information from `User_Activity` which has a ForeignKey to the former. However, even testing this method in the Django console doesn't work:

```
a = Base_Activity.objects.filter(topics__slug = topic)
a.user_activity_set.all()
AttributeError: 'InheritanceQuerySet' object has no attribute 'user_activity_set'
```

---

**Question:** What is the best way to do my query? If this is indeed by following the ForeignKey backwards, then what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = Base_Activity.objects.filter(topics__slug = topic)
```

This returns a QuerySet instance, not a model instance. You should iterate through it or just get one from the list:

```
activities = Base_Activity.objects.filter(topics__slug=topic)
activities[0].user_activity_set.all()
```

In your case you can do entire work in one query:

```
activities = Base_Activity.objects.filter(topics__slug=topic).exclude(user_activity__user=user, user_activity__is_archived=True)
```

Comment: Hi raacer, this is exactly the answer I hoped for. `user_activity_set.all()` now works, but as you point out, I should do my query like your line in the update. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will solve your problem, but anyway **please don't use underscores in your class names in Python**.

Comment: Hi raacer, can you explain me why this is a bad idea?

Comment: Just because following the coding conventions makes life much easier :)

Comment: PEP 8 says: "Almost without exception, class names use the CapWords convention. Classes for internal use have a leading underscore in addition." Follow this link for more info  http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/